# PHP ftp_connect errors

Tags: php

I am trying to connect ftp using PHP and thats my function

```
private function ftpConnect() {
    $this->ftpConn = ftp_connect($this->ftp["server"]);
    $ftpLogin = ftp_login($ftpConn, $this->ftp["user"], $this->ftp["pass"]);
    // check connection
    if ((!$this->ftpConn) || (!$ftpLogin)) {
        echo "Connection Failed!\n";

    }
}
```

but i am getting warnig "Undefined variable: ftpConn "  and "Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given".

What i am doing wrong??

Comment: Change `ftp_login($ftpConn` to `ftp_login($this->ftpConn`. Or `$this->ftpConn = ` to `$ftpConn = `.

Comment: now getting this error only Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: That means the connection to the FTP server failed and the value of the variable is `false`.

Comment: does it mean i am passing wrong user id /pass?

Comment: No, it fails on `ftp_connect` which is before login. So either the server name is wrong (check the value of `$this->ftp["server"]`), either the server uses a different port that you should specify, or the server doesn't accept connections, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres something I made earlier, perhaps its of some interest.

```
<?php 
/**
 * A simple FTP helper class
 */
Class ftp{

    public $status;

    function __construct($host, $user, $pass){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->status = 'Ready';
    }

    private function connect(){
        if (!isset($this->ftp)){
            $this->ftp = ftp_connect($this->host, 21, 3) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
            ftp_login($this->ftp, $this->user, $this->pass) or die("Cannot login, wrong username or password");
            ftp_pasv($this->ftp, true);
            $this->status = 'Connected';
        }
    }

    public function ftp_get_contents($ftp_path, $local_file){
        $this->connect();
        if(ftp_get($this->ftp, $local_file, $ftp_path,  FTP_BINARY)) {
            $this->status = 'Download complete';
        }else{
            $this->status = 'Cannot download';
        }
    }

    public function ftp_put_contents($local_file, $ftp_path){
        $this->connect();
        if(ftp_put($this->ftp, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            $this->status = 'Upload complete';
        }else{
            $this->status = 'Cannot upload';
        }
    }

    public function ftp_delete_file($ftp_path){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_delete($this->ftp, $ftp_path)) {
            $this->status = "$ftp_path deleted successfully";
        }else{
            $this->status = "Could not delete $ftp_path";
        }
    }

    public function ftp_make_dir($dir){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_mkdir($this->ftp, $dir)) {
            $this->status = "Successfully created $dir";
        } else {
            $this->status = "Could not create $dir";
        }
    }

    public function ftp_delete_dir($dir){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_rmdir($this->ftp, $dir)) {
            $this->status = "Successfully deleted $dir";
        } else {
            $this->status = "Could not delete $dir";
        }
    }

    public function show_files($dir='/'){
        $this->connect();
        return ftp_nlist($this->ftp, $dir);
    }

    private function close(){
        ftp_close($this->ftp);
    }

    function __destruct(){
        if(isset($this->ftp)){
            $this->close();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Example usage:

```
<?php 
$ftp = new ftp('ftp.example.com', 'user', 'pass');

echo '<pre>'.print_r($ftp->show_files(), true).'</pre>';
?>
```